# Editing docx in python

Tags: python, xml, ms-word, docx

I want to modify .docx document by finding some variable in it and replace it to another text.
Variables are in specific format: .
The problem is how my variables look in Word's .xml files:

```
<w:r w:rsidR="007F79D3">
    <w:t><$</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00D32AE2">
    <w:t>var</w:t>
</w:r>-<w:r w:rsidR="007F79D3">
    <w:t>></w:t>
</w:r>
```

Is there any good way to replace my variable? Or maybe can I somehow force Word to save variables in one .xml tag?

Comment: Is that XML copied *literally* out of your file? (It's malformed, that's why I ask.) Furthermore: `rsid` refers to the text's editing history. Unless you edited all of your vars the same time and date, the format will be different for other vars. Test what happens when you force-accept all changes. (Also: some crucial information disappeared due to markup. *What* format are your variables in?)

Comment: How to force-accept the changes?
It is XML copied from file, that's how word saves it.

Comment: "Accept all changes" is a Word option.